# How to read data from iCoud email and calendar with rest Api

Tags: c#, typescript

I am building an application with typescript and ASP.Net core. I want to login to iCloud and read emails and also want to read and write calendar events from my application.

Where can I find a full documentation using which I can accomplish this?